# Pass directory name to askopenfilename

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have three functions; with `dirBut` the user selects a directory the output of which goes into `dirname` and updates an `Entry` box. In the third function, `dataInput`, the user selects a file. I would like the open file dialog to open in the directory previously selected by the user and defined by `dirname`, however, I'm not sure how to pass `dirname` to a handle so I can use it in `askopenfilename` since `askdirectory` is called from a button.

```
def UserFileInput(self,status,name):
    row = self.row
    optionLabel = tk.Label(self)
    optionLabel.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky='w')
    optionLabel["text"] = name
    text = status
    var = tk.StringVar(root)
    var.set(text)
    w = tk.Entry(self, textvariable= var)
    w.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='ew')
    self.row += 1

    return w, var


def askdirectory(self):
    dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
    if dirname:
      self.directoryEntry.delete(0, tk.END)
      self.directoryEntry.insert(0, dirname)


def askfilename(self):
  filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=dirname)
  if filename:
    self.dataInput.delete(0, tk.END)
    self.dataInput.insert(0, filename)

currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
directory,var = self.UserFileInput(currentDirectory, "Directory")
self.directoryEntry = directory

dirBut = tk.Button(self, text='Select directory...', command = self.askdirectory)
dirBut.grid(row=self.row-1, column=2)

dataInput, var = self.UserFileInput("", "Data input")
self.dataInput = dataInput

fileBut = tk.Button(self, text='Select input file...', command = self.askfilename)
fileBut.grid(row=self.row-1, column=2)
```

Comment: Please provide the part of the code that calls `askfilename`. (or, if possible, provide the entire script)

Comment: @Mark, editing your question removing and adding different parts is certainly not helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `askdirectory` and `askfilename` belong to the same class, try assigning the directory to `self.dirname` instead of `dirname`. Then the variable will be visible anywhere within the class.

```
def askdirectory(self):
    self.dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
    if self.dirname:
      self.directoryEntry.delete(0, tk.END)
      self.directoryEntry.insert(0, self.dirname)


def askfilename(self):
  filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=self.dirname)
  if filename:
    self.dataInput.delete(0, tk.END)
    self.dataInput.insert(0, filename)
```